# How to exit JavaFX fullscreen stage on mouse click?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

There is Key combination method available as follows:

```
stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
```

Is there any way to capture mouse click or any combination of touchscreen KIOSK to exit full-screen lock?

Comment: Got answer  pane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
       @Override
       public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        System.out.println("Event Called");
           if(mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
               if(mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2){
                   System.out.println("Double clicked");
               }
           }
       }
   });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in callback for that, but you can do it simply with an `EventFilter`:

```
primaryStage.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
    if (primaryStage.isFullScreen() && event.isShortcutDown() && event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

Example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FullScreen extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (primaryStage.isFullScreen() && event.isShortcutDown() && event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane()));
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

*Note:*

I cannot try it out right now, but on touchscreen I would expect, that the same approach is working by using [`SwipeEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/SwipeEvent.html)s.

Comment: Solved my purpose.. Thanks :)